# Fix linting errors in yaml files

Tags: python, yaml, lint

I wanted to fix the errors that *yamllint* gives. Like *autotpep8* automatically formats python code to PEP8 style, do we have something similar for yaml files? Or is there any plugins available in VSCode & Pycharm?

Answer (score 9):

Use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) for VSCODE.
It provides comprehensive YAML Language support to Visual Studio Code, via the yaml-language-server, with built-in Kubernetes and Kedge syntax support.

Press `(Ctrl + Shift + O)` or in Mac `(option⌥ + shift⇧ + F)` for Document Outlining.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, great!

Comment: Doesn't work at all. I have plugin installed. Doesn't say anything about bad yaml. Ctrl + Shift + O only says "The active text editor does not provide symbol information"

Answer (score 0):

The authors of yamllint recommend installing [this VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fnando.linter), which uses yamllint (and other linters).

[This plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15349-yamllint) claims to use yamllint with PyCharm.  It looks pretty new.

Answer (score -1):

This probably doesn't fix all of the linting errors that you'll get,
but the following Python program will remove any unnecessary quotes
around scalars, normalise the YAML, e.g. with reqards to indentation
of block style sequences and mappings:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# uncomment the next line to change the default indentation (mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0) 
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(sys.stdin)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

The above works as a pipe, you can replace the last two lines by:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(sys.argv[1])
data = yaml.load(path)
yaml.dump(data, path)
```

to read from, and write to, a file, for which the name is the first argument provided to the script.

Comment: ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml

Comment: ruamel.yaml is not part of the standard library. you have to install it from PyPI using `pip`